# AWS Beanstalk django 1.5 application not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS so please help me. I'll write only the things which might matter for my problem. If you need more info, just write in comments section.
When I ping ELB address or app address, I get "Request timeout".

Server:

```
Instance type: micro
Custom AMI: ami-c37474b7
```

Load balancer:

```
Only HTTP, port 80
```

And RDS, S3, ElastiCache, SQS.

I use S3 also to store django's static files, which works, because I can see those files in my bucket.
RDS and SQS also works. The problem with ElastiCache is timeout, which libmemcached fired, but that isn't the main problem.

sg-cced0da3 | SecurityGroup for ElasticBeanstalk environment.

```
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   sg-ceed0da1
```

sg-ceed0da1 | ELB created security group used when no security group is specified during ELB creation - modifications could impact traffic to future ELBs

```
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
```

Config file

```
packages: 
  yum:
    libevent: []
    libmemcached: []
    libmemcached-devel: []

container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  02_syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  03_createadmin:
    command: "utilities/scripts/createadmin.py"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: findtofun/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: findtofun.settings
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: ...
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value: ...
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
    option_name: /static/
    value: static/
```

LOGS

---

### /var/log/eb-tools.log

- 2013-06-03 14:52:47,908 [INFO] (27814 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info]
  Script succeeded.
- 2013-06-03 14:52:47,908 [INFO] (27814 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Executing script:
- /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py
- 2013-06-03 14:52:50,019 [INFO] (27814 MainThread) [directoryHooksExecutor.py-29] [root directoryHooksExecutor info] Output from script: New python executable in
- /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.6
- Installing

---

### /var/log/httpd/error_log

- Python/2.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
- [Mon Jun 03    16:53:06 2013] [error] Exception KeyError:
  KeyError(140672020449248,)    in     ignored
- [Mon Jun 03 14:53:06 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting    down
- [Mon Jun 03 14:53:08 2013] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled
  (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
- [Mon Jun 03 14:53:08 2013] [notice]    Digest: generating secret for digest authentication
- ...
- [Mon Jun 03    14:53:08 2013] [notice] Digest: done
- [Mon Jun 03 14:53:08 2013]    [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2
- Python/2.6.8    configured -- resuming normal operations List item

---

### /opt/python/log/supervisord.log

```
2013-06-03 04:39:35,544 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)  
2013-06-03 04:39:35,650 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized  
2013-06-03 04:39:35,651 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking  
2013-06-03 04:39:35,651 INFO supervisord started with pid 3488  
2013-06-03 04:39:36,658 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3498  
2013-06-03 04:39:37,660 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)  
2013-06-03 04:44:51,265 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)  
2013-06-03 04:44:52,280 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 3804  
2013-06-03 04:44:53,283 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,986 INFO stopped: httpd (exit status 0)  
2013-06-03 14:53:08,000 INFO spawned: 'httpd' with pid 27871  
2013-06-03 14:53:09,003 INFO success: httpd entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

---

### /var/log/cfn-init.log

```
2013-06-03 14:53:05,520 [DEBUG] Running test for command 03_createadmin  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,535 [DEBUG] Test command output:  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,536 [DEBUG] Test for command 03_createadmin passed  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,986 [INFO] Command 03_createadmin succeeded  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,987 [DEBUG] Command 03_createadmin output:  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,987 [DEBUG] No services specified  
2013-06-03 14:53:05,994 [INFO] ConfigSets completed  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,000 [DEBUG] Not clearing reboot trigger as scheduling support is not available  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,292 [DEBUG] CloudFormation client initialized with endpoint   https://cloudformation.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,292 [DEBUG] Describing resource AWSEBAutoScalingGroup in stack  arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:352769977590:stack/awseb-e-bwrsuih23z-stack/52c9b3c0-cbf6-11e2-ace7-5017c2ccb886  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,489 [DEBUG] Not setting a reboot trigger as scheduling support is not available  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,510 [INFO] Running configSets: Hook-EnactAppDeploy  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,511 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-EnactAppDeploy  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,512 [INFO] Running config Hook-EnactAppDeploy  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,512 [DEBUG] No packages specified  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,512 [DEBUG] No groups specified  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,512 [DEBUG] No users specified  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,513 [DEBUG] No sources specified  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,513 [DEBUG] /etc/httpd/conf.d/01ebsys.conf already exists  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,513 [DEBUG] Moving /etc/httpd/conf.d/01ebsys.conf to /etc/httpd/conf.d/01ebsys.conf.bak  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,513 [DEBUG] Writing content to /etc/httpd/conf.d/01ebsys.conf  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,514 [DEBUG] No mode specified for /etc/httpd/conf.d/01ebsys.conf  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,514 [DEBUG] Running command aclean  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,514 [DEBUG] No test for command aclean  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,532 [INFO] Command aclean succeeded  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,533 [DEBUG] Command aclean output:  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,533 [DEBUG] Running command clean  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,534 [DEBUG] No test for command clean  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,547 [INFO] Command clean succeeded  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,548 [DEBUG] Command clean output:  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,548 [DEBUG] Running command hooks  
2013-06-03 14:53:06,548 [DEBUG] No test for command hooks  
2013-06-03 14:53:19,278 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded  
2013-06-03 14:53:19,279 [DEBUG] Command hooks output: Executing directory: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/  
Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/01flip.py  
Output from script: httpd: stopped  
httpd: started  
httpd RUNNING pid 27871, uptime 0:00:03  

Script succeeded.  
Executing script: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/09clean.sh  
Output from script:  
Script succeeded.
```

Comment: Sorry for too much edits. I was struggling with unindented code.

Comment: Try to go to the machine through SSH and see what's happening there

Comment: I went, activated virutalenv, started server on port 8000 and there's no errors. What else can I check? Also httpd and python are running.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the right answer, but I guess it works when I put DEBUG = False in settings.py file. Can someone clarify this.